# How to display field from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to display a field from my MySQL database.  It's in the table `tblproducts` in the row with the `id` is set to `1`.  And under the column `qty`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database_name");
$available = "SELECT qty FROM tblproducts WHERE id = 1";
$result = mysql_query($available);  
echo $result;
?>
```

However, I keep getting this message:  `Resource id #2`

I've done a bit of research and seen where other people are having similar problems but most of them are trying to display their data in an HTML table whereas I just need the data from 'qty' to display.  And of course I'm definitely not a MySQL guru.

Can anyone help me out with this please?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: a. Switch to mysqli or PDO.
b. `$result` is just a resource. You still need to extract the content from it, as @Marc B says

Comment: please read documentation about php and mysql stuff, then ask questions.

Comment: Have you looked at other examples of this during that bit of research and copied what they were doing?  Hint: Even though you're only extracting a single value from the database, you're still getting back a *set* of results.  That set simply contains only one record, which itself contains only one field.  But the code doesn't make that distinction.  It's still a set and needs to be treated as such.  Imagine an array with only one element in it.  It's still an array.  You need to index it to extract that one element.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and stop using the **"now deprecated"** MySQL_ - [Use MySQLi_ and/or PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
$result = mysql_query($available);
```

To this:

```
$result = mysql_result(mysql_query($available), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the start. (I'll assume you have the connection set)

**Form the query**

`` $query = "SELECT `qty` 
          FROM `tblproducts` 
          WHERE `id` = 1"; ``

**Execute the query**

`$run = mysql_query($query);`

**Now, put the result in an assoc array**

`$r = mysql_fetch_array($run);`

**See the contents of the array**

`echo $r['qty'];`

It's also advised that you move up from mysql to either mysqli, or PDO. PDO is preferred as you're not bound to the MySQL database model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Here you need to generate associative array and then get the resulting row.

```
$query = "SELECT `qty` FROM `tblproducts` WHERE `id` = 1";
$run = mysql_query($query);
$r = mysql_fetch_array($run);
echo $r['qty'];
```

-
Thanks